# Can I have a virus/adware in my router?

Tags: virus

When I browse the Internet (in any browser), there are extra ads. I thought it could be on my computer, tried Ubuntu live disk, and even there were these ads. Same ads are on my iOS and Android devices too. I did a hard reset on my mobile devices, but that didn't help either.

I think these ads come from either my ISP or my router. Can I have a virus in my router? How can I check it? Are there any other possible variants?

Comment: nice welcome page you have on your website :)

Comment: Have you enabled something like `Mobile Bookmarks` (are there `Mobile Cookies` too?)? Are the ads there when you're not going thru your router and ISP?

Comment: @ott--, i solved it. They come from my ISP, i'm going to prosecute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check your DNS Settings on your router and may reset it or change it to an Open one (Google, OpenDNS,..).

> Then you also need to prevent the attack from happening again.
>   Measures to do that include:
>
> - performing a factory reset to clear any settings left by the    attackers
> - installing the latest router firmware
> - using a strong password on the configuration interface
> - limit access to the configuration interface to appropriate places    (wired, local connections, not the internet)
> - log out of the configuration interface after use (and do not tick    'save password' on your browser when configuring the router)
> - changing the IP addresses used and supplied by the router (for    example change from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.123.1)

posted by @James Snell

You can find some more information here: [How to get rid of an Ad bot?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66070/how-to-get-rid-of-an-ad-bot)

Answer (score 1):

Yes your router might be infected with a Malware.

The best way to find out is to disconnect your computer from the home network and connect to your mobile device using 3/4G (HotSpot)

If you can browse the internet without ads then I suppose your router is compromised.

Comment: To do this test, they'd have to make sure the HotSpot was _not_ provided by their own ISP. The OP indicated that the ISP might also be the source of the ads.

Comment: Yes that is correct.